# List as an argument in R

Tags: r, list, egg

This might be a fairly banal question. I am a r-user who knows little about coding.

I am using the package 'EGAnet' and create a plot using the function EGA. This function has a 'plot.args' argument. From the ?EGA page

> plot.args
> List. A list of additional arguments for the network plot.

> For plot.type = "GGally" (see ggnet2 for full list of arguments):

> vsize Size of the nodes. Defaults to 6.

> label.size Size of the labels. Defaults to 5.

> alpha The level of transparency of the nodes, which might be a single value or a vector of values. Defaults to 0.7.

> edge.alpha The level of transparency of the edges, which might be a single value or a vector of values. Defaults to 0.4.

> legend.names A vector with names for each dimension

> color.palette The color palette for the nodes. For custom colors, enter HEX codes for each dimension in a vector. See color_palette_EGA for more details and examples

I can't figure out how to modify the parameters of this list to add them to the function EGA. For instance, I'd like to change the color.palette (color.palette = "grayscale") and vsize (vsize = 8) arguments.

How do I create this list to add to the function?

The final function looks something like

```
ega.sds <- EGA(data = ex_graph, model = "glasso", plot.EGA = T, plot.args = ???)
```

What do I add in place of ???

Thank you a million.

Comment: Try using `plot.args = list(color.palette = "grayscale", vsize = 8)` as an argument to your call to `EGA`

Comment: As simple as this eh? I feel like an idiot. Thank you very much, it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you just need to write:

```
plot.args = list(
   color.palette = "grayscale",
   vsize = 8
)
```